# ARC clearing memory only when app goes to background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

In my app, the memory is increasing while I add subviews and it is not getting cleared after I remove them from superview. I used the allocation instruments and found that memory is cleared correctly when the app goes to background state and then comes back to the foreground state.

Is this the default behaviour? Can I simulate the situation so that the memory is cleared correctly?

Comment: Post the code where you remove the views from the superviews. Likely you have a strong reference to them. Merely removing them from their superview isn't enough, you have to deallocate them by setting your strong reference to `nil`.

Comment: @BenPious - [self.someView removeFromSuperView]. If I use self.someView = nil, I wont be able to show it a second time, right.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make a new view when you want to show it again. The overhead for this is usually very small, though it depends what kind of view `someView` is.

Comment: @BenPious - But I have created the view in the same nib as the superview. So if I l set it to nil, how can I load the specific view from nib? Also the memory is getting cleared when I move to background. So i guess issue is not with the strong reference.

Comment: If you want to keep a pointer to this view then why are you surprised if the memory blocks it occupies are not flushed?   You can't have your cake and eat it too...

Comment: @Jef - I have lots of subviews that I need to load on different button clicks. So I just want the specific subview to be in the memory at a time. I want only one piece of cake at a time, don't want all pieces in my hand for a given time.

Comment: if you want to keep the memory until the view is needed then you need to create these views lazily (ad-hoc) as needed.  Either remove them from the nib/storyboard and learn to create them programmatically (not difficult at all) or reload the view, with a different nib for each configuration (possibly slightly more difficult) or do exactly as you are. but understand that these views will be occupying some memory until the fat lady sings. (is this such a big deal? are you getting memory warnings?)